# Get a list of Possible flows from an execution like say a user task or a gateway in Activiti?

Tags: java, web-applications, activiti, bpmn, business-process

I am new to Activiti and am trying to integrate it with a web-application. I was going through the APIs and the DB to figure out if there was a way to get a list of possible flows from a gateway or a task (say which has been coupled with a boundary event of some sort)? In other words, what all paths are possible from a given task along with the conditions that one needs to satisfy in order to take that possible path?

I tried searching for this question on the forum/google but could not find the right topic. In case it has already been answered can you please point me to the source.

Thanks in advance

Himanshu

Comment: Using camunda this should be possible with the bpmn model api: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-model. I just cannot tell whether you are working with activiti or camunda based on your text/tags.

Comment: @JanGalinski: I am working with Activiti. Have edited the tags now.
Can you advise me on how to do it in Activiti? Through some digging on the internet, I found some references to pvm. But I am not too familiar with that or how to use it here (could not find any good online sources either)

Comment: Sorry, I switched to camunda when they forked activiti and the bpmn model api is camunda specific.

Comment: @janGalinski: No worries. Here is hoping someone else comes forward :) Could you point me to some good sources for reading about PVM and how they are important to a BPMN engine like Activiti, Camunda?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. But I have used the following snippet and it works for me

```
       UserTask taskNode = null;
        if(node instanceof UserTask)
        {
            taskNode = (UserTask)node;
        }
        if(taskNode != null)
        {

                List<SequenceFlow> sequenceFlows = taskNode.getOutgoingFlows();
                for(SequenceFlow sequenceFlow : sequenceFlows)
                {
                    System.out.println(sequenceFlow.getName()+" "+sequenceFlow.getConditionExpression());
                }
        }
```